# Laravel 5 - Route with parameter not rendering the view correctly

Tags: laravel, parameters, routes, rendering

So I have this routes defined in my routes.php file.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'personaje'], function () {

    Route::get('{pjid}', 'PersonajeController@verPj');
    Route::get('editar/{pjid}', 'PersonajeController@editarPj');
});
```

And this is my controller functions:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Auth;
use DB;

class PersonajeController extends Controller {

    public function editarPj($pjId) {

        if (Auth::check())
        {   
            $usuario = Auth::user();
            $id = $usuario->id;
            $personaje = DB::table('personajes')->where('idusuario', '=', $id)->where('id', '=', $pjId)->get();
            return view('editarpj', ['pj' => $personaje]);
        }

        return redirect('/login');
    }

    public function verPj($pjId) {

        if (Auth::check())
        {   
            $usuario = Auth::user();
            $id = $usuario->id;
            $personaje = DB::table('personajes')->where('idusuario', '=', $id)->where('id', '=', $pjId)->get();
            return view('verpj', ['pj' => $pjId]);
        }
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

When I try to access' localhost/personaje/5' for example, the view will not render using the blade template. It appears like this:

https://gyazo.com/689f64007e239e072c56b8307278d178

But if I remove the parameter in the routes.php file and the controller functions, when I try to access 'localhost/personaje/', the view renders correctly, like this:

https://gyazo.com/8fbb7166df1b4aea3cd12748ad25df2e

The view only has a navbar and that's it, it doesn't use the parameter for anything yet. Why does this happen? I have been messing with this for days and I can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: looks like a asset link issue..try to add / in your css link. like this

<link href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> note the slash (/) at the beginning.

Pls paste your css header links so we can check.

Answer (score 1):

The first route is likely catching both routes.

Try

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'personaje'], function () {
    Route::get('editar/{pjid}', 'PersonajeController@editarPj');
    Route::get('{pjid}', 'PersonajeController@verPj');
});
```

It's good practice to place the most specific routes on top so the more generic routes don't get in the way.

Comment: Didn't fix it. It's weird. If you remove the parameters from the routes and the controllers, the view is rendered correctly. If you keep them, the view is not rendered correctly. I'm thinking this could be a bug in Laravel 5.1

Comment: Do you have another route which would be capturing `localhost/personjae`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's still relevant, but for those who still seek the solution:
when linking your CSS or JS instead of

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/myCSS.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myJS.js"></script>`

do

`<link rel="stylesheet" href={{ asset("css/myCSS.css") }}>
<script type="text/javascript" src={{ asset("js/myJS.js") }}></script>`

Had the same problem recently, this is what solved it.
Cheers!